# wordpress theme header not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, formatting

My wordpress page isn't loading the header file properly and as a result the formatting of the page is thrown out. Here is my page and code below. Any help would be really appreciated.

I've added the mailchimp sign up to the header, I don't think this has screwed it up as when I remove this the page still renders badly.

http://gd.beneversfield.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <title><?php wp_title(' | ', 1, right); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <?php $br0_option = br0_get_global_options(); ?>  
    <style type="text/css"><?php if (array_key_exists('br0_genstyles',$br0_option)) {echo $br0_option['br0_genstyles'];} ?></style>   

    <!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_IE9.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_IE.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php if (array_key_exists('br0_gencode',$br0_option)) {echo $br0_option['br0_gencode'];} ?>
    </script>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>



<div id="content">
<header>

<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://giantdwarf.us3.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=33d7cfaaa330870d4e469e4cd&id=13df6f834d" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list:</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_33d7cfaaa330870d4e469e4cd_13df6f834d" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->


    <div class="header_wrapper">
            <a href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>"><img class="logo" src="<?php if (array_key_exists('br0_logourl',$br0_option)) {echo $br0_option['br0_logourl'];} ?>" alt="logo" /></a>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_id' => 'menu_wrapper', 'menu_class' => 'main_menu', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span><span class="menu_background"></span>', 'items_wrap'      => '<span class="menu_title">MENU</span><div class="menu_arrow"></div><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>') ); ?>
    </div><!-- header_wrapper -->

</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you test the page by removing this code in header. I think this will solve your issue

add a `</style>` tag next to the `wp_head();` . I found some custom plugin or some other `plugin is adding the css <style> using the`wp_head()`but it is not adding the style end tag </style>.` So you add this and try.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but I tried it and it didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: add </style>  next to  <?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: You got it! Thanks so much for your help Ananth!